# Integrating over the rate of change to find x

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration

I am stuck trying to turn a graph of dx/dt vs time into a graph of x in each bin vs time.

I have a large dataset of galaxies. For each galaxy there is an array which is the rate of change in mass over time, ie dM/dt. So for each galaxy there is a 1d array declaring the dM/dt at certain intervals of time. I also have a time array. I can make a plot of dM/dt versus time and see the rate of change over the course of the universe.

However now I want to make a different plot with the mass of the galaxy at each time. Ie how much mass has formed in each time interval. I'm trying to integrate over each array but that just gives me the total mass at the end. I want the masses at each interval so I can make a plot.

This is the array of dM/dt for the galaxy 1.

```
`[ 1.34162134e+10  1.00928939e+11  6.60376576e+10  3.42446745e+11
    2.73107925e+11  1.91493528e+11  6.73213607e+11  8.64649622e+11
    2.05433614e+11  8.47043150e+11  3.87556687e+11  1.67345819e+11
    5.12216609e+11  1.87612654e+12  7.74310416e+11 -5.22415543e+09
   -1.25683250e+11 -5.54250651e+10 -3.76655769e+10 -1.59683145e+10
    2.82219633e+11  6.00554078e+11  3.44238577e+11  2.79598376e+11
    1.05315182e+11 -3.21916236e+11 -1.50353059e+10  4.55187056e+10
   -3.65908025e+10  7.60636622e+10  6.41365631e+10  7.13690729e+10
    1.05199767e+11]`
```

And here's the time array. Units in Gyr but not important.

```
`[ 0.418  0.547  0.687  0.844  1.036  1.282  1.54   1.944  2.384  2.839
 3.285  3.744  4.206  4.657  5.115  5.577  6.073  6.522  6.998  7.453
 7.932  8.432  8.902  9.389  9.837 10.299 10.834 11.323 11.824 12.337
12.795 13.328 13.803]`
```

Then of course I can plot a graph of these two:
[graph of galaxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7nuy.png)

Now I want to plot a graph of the mass formed in each interval and plot that against time (I hope this makes sense). So I would need to integrate the first array over each time interval. I'm having trouble though. This is what I have so far

```
` for i in range(galaxyarray.shape[0]): # for i in number of galaxies

      for j in range(galaxyarray.shape[1]): # for j in each element

         result = integrate.trapz((Mhdotarr[i,j]), time)`
```

but that's not working. I can get the total mass formed over time by integrating over the whole array, but I want to get the mass at each interval. I hope this makes sense?

To look something like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfJYE.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for cumulative integration. To do this swap `trapz` for `cumtrapz`

```
for i in range(galaxyarray.shape[0]): # for i in number of galaxies
      for j in range(galaxyarray.shape[1]): # for j in each element

         result = integrate.cumtrapz((Mhdotarr[i,j]), time)
```

This returns an array of mass over time where the final element is the final mass.